# Adding HTTP header to d3.json with queue.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, queue.js

I'm aware that I can add a header to a D3 JSON request by doing the following:

```
d3.json("http://localhost:8080/data")
  .header("Application-ID", "1")
```

But how do I add this header when using queue's defer?

```
queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "http://localhost:8080/data")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d3.json` doesn't actually perform the request until you call `get`. So, if your goal is to make a deferred http request, you can just do:

```
var req = d3.json("http://localhost:8080/data")
    .header("Application-ID", "1");
queue().defer(req.get);
```